# Fluid dynamics - immiscible liquids

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics

Question:
A U-tube of uniform cross-section is partially filled with a liquid I. Another liquid-II, which does not mix with liquid I is poured into one side. It is found that the liquid levels of the two sides of the tube are the same while the level of liquid-I has risen by 2cm. If the specific gravity of liquid-I is 1.1, what will be the specific gravity of liquid-II?

My logic:
Shouldn't the specific gravity be the same? Otherwise the two levels would never become the same. There is the same height of liquid 2 as the height that liquid 1 has risen by. So both will exert the same pressure. But obviously my logic is flawed as the answer is 1.12

Comment: Why is it voting to be closed?

Comment: The close votes so far are all in reference to the [homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714). I actually think this isn't necessarily in violation of the policy, but I could see arguments either way. Know that many veterans of this site have grown weary with the flood of homework, and we see too many "but I even showed all my work, why not tell me where I'm wrong?" complaints (missing the fact that there must be a concept there too), so questions that look vaguely like "<problem> <work> <what went wrong?>" provoke a negative reaction.

Comment: So why not just make a policy of not allowing homework questions at all? @ChrisWhite

Comment: That discussion can be found in many threads [on meta](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework). In particular check out [Bite-sizing homework](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5958). I think it's fair to say we struggle with trying to filter out people trying to get us to do their work for them (we're not interested, and it only hurts the students, and it's unfair to everyone else in the class), but at the same time be useful as a resource for students whose questions are inspired by their homework (as good homework tends to inspire further questions).

Comment: Yes but the post should at least be read before voting it down. I don't think there is anything more I can do to make the question in accordance with the homework policy. @ChrisWhite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific gravities would be the same if the levels of the two side were the same after liquid-II was added.

When I try this, my logic seems to be flawed too. I don't get 1.12.

The level on side II has not changed. The level on side I has risen 2 cm. So 2 cm of liquid-II were added.

Consider the horizontal plane 2 cm below the top of side II. Below this level on both sides there is liquid-I

Above this level on side 2, there is 2 cm of liquid-II. Above this on side I, there is 4 cm of liquid-1. That should tell you the answer.